# If user clicks object attribute, how to only show objects with that attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

If a user clicks one of these icons:

home.html.erb:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture", id="challenge-category"></span> #challenge.categorization: "adventure"
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart", id="challenge-category"></span> #challenge.categorization: "health"
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase", id="challenge-category"></span> #challenge.categorization: "work"
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart", id="challenge-category"></span> #challenge.categorization: "buy"
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass", id="challenge-category"></span> #challenge.categorization: "wacky"
```

How to only show a user's challenges that share the clicked `categorization`?

db:

```
create_table "challenges", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "categorization"
end
```

challenge.rb:

```
CATEGORIZATION = ['adventure', 'health', 'work', 'buy', 'wacky']
scope :adventure,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Adventure') }
scope :health,  -> { where(categorizations: 'health') }
scope :work,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Work') }
scope :buy,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Buy') }
scope :wacky,  -> { where(categorizations: 'Wacky') }
scope :goal,  -> { where(categories: 'Goal') }
scope :habit,  -> { where(categories: 'Habit') }
```

controller:

```
def home
  @challenges = current_user.challenges.order("deadline ASC")
  @adventure_challenges = current_user.challenges.adventure.order("deadline ASC")
  @health_challenges = current_user.challenges.health.order("deadline ASC")
  @work_challenges = current_user.challenges.work.order("deadline ASC")
  @buy_challenges = current_user.challenges.buy.order("deadline ASC")
  @wacky_challenges = current_user.challenges.wacky.order("deadline ASC")
end
```

I included javascript/jquery as tags because it would be a more elegant solution to avoid page reload, but not necessary for purposes of this question.

How do I rewrite home.html.erb so that when a glyphicon is clicked the page will reload (or JavaScript is trigged) and then only the challenges with the same `categorization` that the glyphicon represents will be shown?

Comment: First of all, you added multiple id attributes with the same id, which might cause issues.
You can change the route in routes.rb so that it accepts an optional param for the category and then use the link_to helper to link to it.
In your controller you will then have that param available as params[:my_param_name] (this is the non js solution)

Comment: @JuliaWill this could be easily converted to a js solution by responding to different formats (e.g. route.json) and just handing back the JSON data through an ajax call. and I agree "challenge-category" should be a class not an id.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, that is very true. But I don't think this is an easy topic to explain in a comment - especially when someone seems to be new to RoR ;)

Comment: Good points @JuliaWill! How would I change the route in routes.rb so that it accepts an optional param for the `categorization`? That's the main thing I'm confused about in your helpful comment

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com assuming your current route would be /challenges, you could add: `get "/challenges(/:category)", to: "challenges#home, as: :my_custom_route_name`. You can also look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for some more info on routing.